# WPF:Auto-Expand RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox in WPF,

```
<RichTextBox Name="_RichTextBox" />
```

And in the code-behind i was able to auto-expand the richtextbox height on the 
text change

```
mRichTextBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;

async void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mRichTextBox.Height = mRichTextBox.Document.LineHeight;
        }
```

But, the LineHeight is coming NaN for me and so does the Height ,

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Any help is Appreciated!!

Comment: is it a possibility to count the lines and add the font height + a constant to that to calculate the height?

Comment: yea i was thinking of that

Comment: i have no practice with RichTextBox, but thats the first what came to my mind..

Comment: It's my last shot
but i was looking for something descent and elegant

Comment: What's wrong with just putting it in a `Grid` with a `RowDefinition Height="Auto"`and letting that do the resizing?

Comment: Could you share little example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Auto Resize` of the `Height` (in *XAML*):

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Height="Auto" Width="200">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

the `Width` is constant. the `Height` is 1 Line, when the Text isn't bigger than one row.

[image: One Line]

One Line

[image: More than one line + Auto Resize]

More than one line + Auto Resize

Comment: Is this possible to do for width? Autoresize width?